Is it possible to charge a zero potential ball?
I've been studying electrostatic potential and capacitance and am curious about the Earth's role in absorbing charge. The Earth is often considered an almost neutral body that can absorb an unlimited amount of charge, but where exactly does this charge go? Is it converted into other forms of energy, or does it escape into space? Furthermore, is there a fixed value for how much charge the Earth can hold, or is it truly unlimited?

Are you assuming that charges that are being absorbed are created from nothing so that somehow there is this extra charge from nowhere?

Hmm then let it be that charges that are being absorbed are not from nowhere and are suddenly from space through giant thunder which hits earth(hypothetically speaking)

What I'm saying is those electrons already had to exist in the environment that encompasses everything including the earth. So the earth couldn't have a large net charge because then there must be a positive charge somewhere else. This is inline with the conservation of charge in Allures answer.

The idea is that the Earth is big enough that a few Avogadro's numbers worth of electrons will have no net impact on the charge of the Earth. It's similar to the concept of the "environment" in thermodynamics, which can absorb or provide an unlimited supply of heat.
Here's one way to think about it. Suppose you have $1C$ of charge in your battery. That's $\approx 6.24 \times 10^{18}$ electrons. Meanwhile, the mass of the Earth is $6\times10^{24}kg$, which means there are approximately $10^{50}$ electrons in the Earth (an extremely handwavy number I arrived at by assuming the Earth is all oxygen). Against that number, $6.24 \times 10^{18}$ disappears into a rounding error, and therefore we can say the Earth can absorb an "unlimited" of charge that you might encounter in your daily life.
Of course, it's not actually unlimited. If you have $10^{20}C$ of charge then the Earth won't be able to absorb all of it. But you're never going to encounter that much charge in real life.
Finally, because charge is conserved, any charge absorbed by the Earth is not converted to "something else". It's just stored "somewhere" in the Earth, contributing to the Earth's electric field (it can, of course, also lead to the Earth attracting positively-charged cosmic rays and increasing the Earth's mass).
